# Were the SPD social fascists?

Tags: political-theory

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_Party_of_Germany

> Throughout the Weimar era, the KPD viewed the Social Democratic Party of Germany (SPD) as its main adversary,[8] and the KPD referred to the SPD as "social fascists."[13]

Does this characterization sound accurate? Is Fascism primarily opinion based?

Comment: We can't reasonably answer the question of whether they *were* fascists. We can only say whether the KPD viewed them as such. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 4):

"Fascist" is both a somewhat narrow/technical term (referring to Mussolini's movement) and an insult flinged at whomever you want to denigrate. The KPD (communists) viewed the SPD as further to the right of them (KPD) on political spectrum, so they dubbed them as some variety of fascists.

Wikipedia actually [explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascism#%22Fascist%22_as_a_pejorative) this distinction reasonably well.

Comment: Good answer but this link would help too. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Democratic_Party_of_Germany